# @query is not working on inherited classes

Tags: angular

Suppose I have :
ConcreteClass extends BaseClass{}

When trying to use @Query(BaseClass) ,
Angular don't find anything.
Only when I am querying for ConcreteClass I get results;
any idea?

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1828

Answer (score 1):

Finding by subclass in `@ViewChild(SubClass)` is not supported.

See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1828

A workaround is explained in https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8580#issuecomment-218525425

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-fancy-item',
  providers: [{provide: MyItem, useExisting: MyFancyItem}]
})
class MyFancyItem extends MyItem {}
```

which makes a query for `MyItem` looks for `MyItem` and `MyFancyItem`. I haven't tried it though.

Comment: Who down-voated this? whats wrong in there?  I upvoated as this suggests correct direction !