# Communication between a lightbox component and its child component?

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have the following markup to display any component within a lightbox:

```
<lightbox>
  <some-comp></some-comp>
</lightbox>
```

I am trying to find *the more generic and Angular way* for both components to communicate (I have read https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction). For instance, the child component might say to the lightbox:

- My content is large so you need to expand.
- I contain a form and here is the data submitted via the form.
- Etc.

**IMPORTANT.** The lightbox doesn't know in advance which type of component it will hold.

I can make it work by injecting a service in both components and the service contains a `Subject` that serves as a communication bus between the two components (this solution is described [in the docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)).

But is there another way? I am developing a UI component library and the service solution forces the users of the library to inject and manipulate a service in every component they display in the lightbox. I'd like to avoid that.

(Another idea that I had was for the lightbox to gain access to its child component and subscribe to a specific property on that component, but it's hard to do in a generic manner.)

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: @Jota.Toledo: I'm well aware of the documentation... It doesn't offer a generic solution, other than injecting a service like I mentioned.

Comment: I guess you could use ng-content + directives in someway so that you can "promise" through the directive some behavior from the component inside of lightbox, something like: https://github.com/Teradata/covalent/blob/develop/src/platform/core/data-table/data-table-table/data-table-table.component.html but I dont have experience in that sense :(

Answer (score 1):

#### pass child to parent explicitly

One way would be to pass the child explicitly

```
  <parent [child]="child">
    <child #child></child>
  </parent>
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/bKII70TgzP5BcJVFVzuw?p=preview)

#### provide a service on the parent

An alternative way is to provide a service on the parent, and inject it in the child component.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/F0624ZwYI0uznKjFpulB?p=preview)

It is better to use observables (`BehaviorSubject`, ...) for communication instead of the simple field approach used in the Plunker.

#### conclusion

In every way, there is some cooperation required, either from the developer who uses the parent component, or the developer who builds supported child components.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I believe those are the same techniques as listed here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction. I was hoping for something a bit more "magical" (from the user's point of view) but you're right, some explicit cooperation is needed.

Comment: That's because that's the docs about this topic ;-) I think the first approach isn't mentioned explicitly though. I'm also not sure if it is mentioned that a projected child can inject a service from the parent node (instead of the host component). I just wanted to highlight this options for this specific use case.

Answer (score -1):

Taking Forward Gunter's answer you can also look at **NGRX**.

It's one of the best ways to communicate between large components and both the components will acts like `Dumb Components` i:e will not have any idea of the type of data each will hold.

Keeping the data at a central location will also help you manage state of the application well which will lead to better flexibility and ability to add future enhancements.

I have a full page dedicated to ngrx(v4) hope it helps [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx)

Comment: @Jota.Toledo but not using ngrx. Shared services and ngrx is different i guess.

Comment: Thanks Ryan thought off but i wanted Everything as angular bases so created a comment section 2 in Angular :)