# is there a way to access content inside a templateRef

Tags: angular

I need to add a attribute to the content via this directive.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myStructuralDirective]'
})
export class MyStructuralDirectiveDirective {
  @Input()
  set myStructuralDirective(key: string) {

    key ? (this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef), this.renderer.setAttribute(...)  ): this.viewContainerRef.clear();
  }

  constructor(
    private readonly renderer: Renderer2,
    private readonly templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private readonly viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
  ) {}
}
```

usage:

```
 <custom-element-1 *myStructuralDirective="classProperty">Test custom element 1</custom-element-1>
```

I don't find any method exposed via `templateRef` to do so.

Comment: It looks like this is not currently supported but there are (hacky) workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49867172/access-host-component-in-a-structural-directive