# Angular 6 Directive: get reference to the host component instance

Tags: angular

Consider this Angular 6 component

```
@Component({
  template: '<div my-directive>content</div>'
})
export class ACustomComponent {}
```

What is the simplest way for me to inject the specific instance of the component inside the directive's constructor?

```
@Directive()
export class MyDirective {
  // how to reference the component whose template hosts this directive?
  constructor(private hostComponent: Component) {}
}
```

The simplest way I've thought to do this is to use a service provided in `@Component()`, store the component instance in a service property, then inject that same service in the directive and retrieve the instance from that property.  Wondering if there is a simpler, more generic way (so I don't have to provide that service every time I need to do this) that means the directive doesn't need to know the type of its host component.

PS: My question is different [from this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46014761/how-to-access-host-component-from-directive) because whereas the other wants the component instance that the directive is directly applied to -- `<my-cmp my-directive></my-cmp>`, I'm asking for the nearest parent component whether the directive is applied to it directly or to a native HTML element within its template.

Basically, the problem I want to solve is: I need to execute methods within the directive and bind them to the `this` context of the component that hosts them without the directive knowing the component's type ahead of time.

```
someMethod.bind(this.hostComponent)();
```

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8277#issuecomment-311032673 if it is helping

Comment: or may be this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8277#issuecomment-323678013

Comment: @ConnorsFan I don't think so. In that posting, the directive is applied specifically to the component, like `<my-cmp my-directive></my-cmp>`. That isn't the case here. I am looking for the nearest parent component whether the directive is applied directly to it or within its template. I'll edit the question a bit to make that clearer.

Comment: @Yousefkhan thanks for the suggestion. The first requires me to inject a provider every time (my current solution), and the second allows me only to access the host if the directive is directly applied to it, like `<my-cmp my-directive/>`

Answer (score 4):

For a dynamic component type,I do like this, it works on Angular 9.

```
export class FromItemComponentBase  {
  constructor(private hostElement: ElementRef) {
    hostElement.nativeElement.__component=this;
  }
}
```

---

```
@Component({
  selector: 'input-error',
  templateUrl: 'component.html'
})
export class FromItemErrorComponent extends FromItemComponentBase {
  constructor(private hostElement: ElementRef) {
    super(hostElement);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'input-password',
  templateUrl: 'component.html'
})
export class FromItemPasswordComponent extends FromItemComponentBase {
  constructor(private hostElement: ElementRef) {
    super(hostElement);
  }
}
```

---

```
@Directive({selector: 'input-error,input-password,input-text'})
export class FormInputDirective {
  component:FromItemComponentBase;

  constructor(private hostElement: ElementRef) {
    this.component=hostElement.nativeElement.__component;
  }
}
```