# Alter host styling from directive

Tags: angular

I have the following:

```
<custom-form-control>
    <input [myDir]="disableValidationStyles" />
</custom-form-control>

@Component({
    selector: 'custom-form-control',
    ...
})
export class CustomFormControlComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
    constructor(public hostRef: ElementRef) { }

    @HostBinding(class.custom-form-control) defaultClass = true;

    disableValidationStyles: boolean = true;
    ...
}

@Directive({
    selector: '[myDir]'
})
export class MyDirective {
    // get reference to host and remove style classes
    // OR
    // prevent validation of form control (and Angular automatically applying 
    // validation styles)
}
```

`myDir` should remove any styling associated with the validation of `custom-form-control` (e.g. `ng-valid`, `ng-touched`, `ng-dirty`). Styles are applied to the host of `CustomFormControlComponent` using `HostBinding`. Generally I've tried the following two methods but to no avail:

1. Get reference to the host component (e.g. DI `ViewContainerRef` into `MyDirective`) and try to change the styles
2. Prevent / alter validation within the directive (e.g DI `NgControl` in `MyDirective` and using `reset()`)

Also tried most of the suggestions from these:

[How to access host component from directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46014761/how-to-access-host-component-from-directive)

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8277

I feel like I've exhausted the options at this point except maybe using a service to coordinate the status changes from the form control but that feels like a very clunky solution. Ideally, I'd like to just disable the validation whenever the directive is applied with the flag (`disableValidationStyles`) set.

Appreciate any insights, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using injected `NgControl` by setting the `control` property to pristine using `markAsPristine` (styles were set based on `ng-touched`, `ng-dirty` classes).