# How to apply a directive to a component that implements a specific interface

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance

I tried to develop a directive to be applied only to components that implements this interface:

```
export interface Openable {
  open: boolean;
}
```

This is used to create components with a togglable ui part, like a custom select input.
The problem is that nothing is working, the interested part won't close.

**This is the directive:**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[elementBlur]',
  standalone: true
})
export class ElementBlurDirective {
  constructor(private host: ElementRef<HTMLElement & Openable>) { }

  @HostListener('document:mousedown', ['$event'])
  handleMouseDown(event: Event): void {
    const target = event.target as HTMLElement;
    const host = this.host.nativeElement;
    if (host && !host.contains(target)) {
      host.open = false;
      console.log("Done")
    };
  }
}
```

The goal is to close the section when the user clicks outside of the element, like a blur event.

**Then, in my component, this is how I apply the directive:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-select',
  templateUrl: './input-select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-select.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: InputSelectComponent,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  hostDirectives: [ElementBlurDirective]
})
export class InputSelectComponent<T> implements ControlValueAccessor, Openable { ... }
```

as I said, in the component template there's a part shown conditionally, based on the property "**open**". But when i clicked outside of it, nothing happens. I tried switching to a class instead of an interface, but i kept getting errors like "Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'open)'". It's like if this component wasn't an instance of the class.
How can I make the directive to be applied only to components that implements the Openable interface and make it work?

Comment: The problem is not in that the directive is not applied but in that `host.nativeElement` is an HTML element and not an instance of the component, so it does not have `open` property. How to access a host component from a directive is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46014761/how-to-access-host-component-from-directive)

Comment: @Shlang thank you for answering. This may solve the problem but up to a half, because I also need the html element to make that check inside the method "handleMouseDown"

Comment: Yeah, and you can inject both - an ElementRef and the component instance

Comment: export class ElementBlurDirective {
...
constructor(private openable: Openable, private element: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {}
...
}
like so? I've tried this but it's giving me the NullInjector error

Comment: Look, for example, [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54143054/8382469) from the question I linked above